# What is with all this font family questions?

Tags: discussion

I have seen this font related  question "font is on topic or off topic" on meta, but what about this kind of questions ?

- [What is a good free font management tool for linux?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4085/what-is-a-good-free-font-management-tool-for-linux)
- [OSX: Thousands of fonts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4083/osx-thousands-of-fonts)
- [Create a font comparison sheet](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4018/create-a-font-comparison-sheet)

I know font is a part of graphic design but do these kind of questions give any help in graphic design?

Mods if you feel that it is completely out of the box question, so dont mind closing this ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think these are fair questions. I see these questions as being "how" questions, but they are not easily answerable with a quick web search to a tutorial.

These may seem (and are) low-level—most are really just about file management after all—but fonts are their own particular file type and usage that requires special handling. Font management has always been a geniune challenge, and all font management software sucks because of the files themselves. This one of the aspects of our work where "the rubber meets the road". Really, what are we without fonts?

Comment: And they do fit the "... and non-designers trying to do their own graphic design" bit in our mission statement, don't you think?